# What other war crimes trials, besides those of Nazi war criminals, were held after WWII?

Tags: world-war-two, nazi-germany, japan, war-crime

Why were the Nuremberg trials after WWII for the Germans only? The same charges used against the the Germans could be easily extended to the Japanese or possibly Italians. They have committed as much war atrocities as the others against the Chinese and POW.
Why was not the Japanese Emperor and his generals charged as most of the German counterparts?

Comment: And if it really was about justice, why not have trials for the allies as well? They committed war crimes as well.

Comment: @HermannIngjaldsson In the Tokyo trial, Justice Pal made the same point as well, and judged the acccused not guilty.

Comment: @user571376: Without in any way impugning Justice Pal's learning or itegrity, I think he got it a bit wrong. One might argue that some of the things the Allies have done count as war crimes (firebombing would be high on the list). However, this in no way acquits the Axis criminals of *their* crimes. Justice Pal ought to have resigned instead of finding the defendants not guilty.

Comment: @FelixGoldberg I would agree with you if this was the only reason behind judging the accused not guilty. But the full order of Justice Pal was a 1200-pages long report, and though it is available for free, I could not make much sense of it. It contains a lot of details related to precedence and jurisprudence. If there is a summary available somewhere, I would be interested.

Comment: It's just weird to put up trials and all, pretending like the matter is about justice when in fact it is about being on the right team. The murderers on the winning team become heroes, the murderers on the loosing team get executed. It's not justice, it's who won.. and we should stop pretending like it is anything else.

Comment: @HermannIngjaldsson: No, it's not as simple as that. People like Arthur Harris might have been given ranks and peerages but they definitely did not become heroes. That's because the good, if flawed, side won: people have access to the records and can judge for themselves the actions of the participants in the war. Had the other, evil, side won, Himmler would have been declared a hero and whoever dissented from that would be swiftly done in. So please, do not confuse flawed good with unalloyed evil.

Comment: Had the other side won the other side would have been viewed as good today and this side would have been viewed as evil. For instance, those who conducted unlimited bombing campaigns over mainland Europe with the sole purpose of murdering as many civilians as possible went home with medals and the highest of honors. The same has been true in pretty much every war since.

Comment: we have pictures of my father in law during ww2 in a court room(he was MP) he is guarding germany soldiers i can remember him sayingit was war trials,but i dont think he said Nuremburg where else could he been talking about.

Comment: Welcome to History Stack Exchange! If you have a NEW question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://history.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. If you have sufficient reputation, [you may upvote](http://history.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) the question. Alternatively, "star" it as a favorite and you will be notified of any new answers.

Comment: @HermannIngjaldsson Well, here we come full circle - it boils down to political theory. In my book, the "general masses" have a chance of actually thinking for themselves, provided they get a decent education. It's a model that works so-so in practice but that's the only viable foundation for a modern democracy. In your model, the masses have no chance of figuring things out, just by dint of being the masses. The necessary corollary is that the masses must be ruled by an overclass of those who can figure things out. Like, say, the Party, be it red or brown.

Comment: Can you scan the picture? Some people here are quite good at solving such puzzles.

Comment: Comments are not for discussion.

Comment: This question would benefit from preliminary research.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Look up the [Tokyo trials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Military_Tribunal_for_the_Far_East). As for the Italians, they weren't implicated in war crimes on the same scale as the Germans and Japanese.

Comment: Thanks you Sir. This is the first time I heard of the Tokyo trials. Most of the documentaries I watched were all about Nuremberg.

Comment: As an addendum,  the japanese Emperor was not judged for political reasons.

Answer (score 7):

Japanese war criminals were [tried in Tokyo after the war](http://www.pbs.org/wgbh/amex/macarthur/peopleevents/pandeAMEX101.html). Generals [Tojo (the former Japanese Prime Minister)](http://www.history.com/this-day-in-history/japanese-war-crimes-trial-begins) and [Yamashita (in charge of the Philippines)](http://www.ess.uwe.ac.uk/wcc/Yamashita1.htm) were hanged as a result.

Comment: The link for the Yamasita trial you have isn't working for me. Also while it is in popular press rather than journal [this account](https://www.washingtonpost.com/archive/opinions/2001/12/30/vengeance-did-not-deliver-justice/072daf87-0f0b-4026-ac40-b8bd4fc2c0b9/) shows that the trial was victor's justice.

Answer (score 2):

The 'big' trial as mentioned above was carried out in Tokyo. But there were numerous other trials of Japanese personnel with various degrees of fairness. My answer is a summary based upon sources that I am familiar with.

- The US

Roger Mansell has a collection of the [American lead trials](http://www.mansell.com/Resources/special_files/special_files.html) under Pacific Area War Crimes Trials, Guam that were mostly held in Guam.

- UK/Commonwealth

Australia and England held trials all over the South Pacific from New Guinea to India. The Singapore trials covered a wide range of crimes, especially the Death railway. [Singapore war crimes trial](http://www.singaporewarcrimestrials.com/background/map) is a pretty informative site that can take you to some better primary documentation.

But despite the desire for justice, most of the Japanese convicted were rehabilitated as Japan became an important buffer in the cold war.

- China (ROC and CCP)

The situation was highly complicated as the Japanese surrendered both to the communists and the KMT. The two acted very differently, [Kushner's Men to Devils](https://www.jstor.org/stable/j.ctt13x0f2w)  is great on this.

- USSR

Many of the Japanese captured were in Manchuria and held by the Soviets essentially without trial. I don't have a great set of sources for this, [here's a NY Times article](http://www.nytimes.com/1998/04/12/world/japan-s-blossoms-soothe-a-pow-lost-in-siberia.html). I am least familiar with this and could use suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

After the Second World War there were over 2200 separate trials of Japanese personnel accused of war crimes (some trials with several defendants). The trials took place in more than 50 places in the Asia-Pacific region.

Comment: This answer would be improved with expansion upon the details and some source references.